# Generate random numbers to be used within a table using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

I'm looking to create a 10x10 table in which the values are randomly generated from 1 to 20.

I have managed to create the table however I can't figure out how to make the value of a cell random, rather than a specific value.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please post the code that you have to generate the table.

Comment: do you mean, you didn't know how to generate random number in c# ?

Comment: Have you considered using the System.Random class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know how to create the random number, just not how to set it as the value for a cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, use `Random` class,

```
    Random r = new Random();
    r.Next(1, 20);
```

A simple 2-D array example,

```
    int[,] arr = new int [10, 10];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int ki = 0; ki < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int kj = 0; kj < 10; j++)
        {
            arr[ki, kj] = r.Next(1, 20);
        }
    }
```